# Best practice on c# razor notification system

Tags: c#, sql, razor, entity-framework-6

I am developing a web application in Razor C# and EntityFramework 6. With the application members can register/login, and ask questions to their friends. Those friends can reply on their questions. A bit like Ask.fm and Sayat.me. Now I want to add a notification icon with a counter.

So the counter will increase when someone has asked a question to a specific member. When the member has read the new question, the notification needs to dissapear for that specific read question.

I am using a SQL database to store all member data and sent and answered questions.

What is the best practice to display a notification (counter) for the number of unread questions/messages?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_badges_labels.asp

Comment: I already know that.. I want to know how to fill these numbers (label value) with data from the database. I want to know the best practice on getting notifications from the database (or is there another way to create notifications on missed messages for a specific user)?